# join points in a graph using matplotlib independent of the sequence of the points in the array

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph that is a scattered xy plot. Is there any way, I can join the points, independent of the sequence of the points in the array? The sequence of joining the points depends on x and not on the sequence in the array. So, basically, the line traverses from left to right.

I am using

```
    plot0.plot(x0, y0, 'ko-', lw=1, color="red",label="dummy")
```

But it connects the points in the order they appear in the array. So the graph becomes a zig-zag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the connecting line to go from left to right then you have to sort your data points in order of increasing x:

```
s = np.argsort(x0)
plt.plot(x0[s], y0[s], 'ko-')
```

Comment: oh.. right, it didnt strike me..Will try and get back.

Comment: ok, this gives the index of the elements. Do I have to iterate x0 and y0 and create  new arrays according to the index in the s? Or is there an easy way?

Comment: You don't have to do anything -- in the above code snippet `x0[s]` gives you a sorted version of `x0` (assuming that `x0` is a numpy array). You might want to read about [Index arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays).